# Is Sigma's lens hood LH-825-03 compatible with a 18-50 2.8 EX DC HSM Macro?

Tags: lens, sigma, compatibility, lens-hood

I'm looking for a replacement hood for my 18-50 f/2.8 EX DC HSM Macro, but I'm not having much success. I've instead found some hoods for the 17-50 OS (stabilized) version, which also has a 72 mm front element and compatible focal lengths.

As this hood snaps to the outer rim of the front element (with a similar mechanism), I'm wondering if it would be compatible with my lens. Does anybody know the degree of standardization?

**UPDATE:** I've been replied by a Sigma distributor, saying that the appropriate replacement is LH780-04. This does not say anything about the compatibility of LH-825-03 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with two pairs of Sigma lenses shows that **no hood fits on any other lens**. You have to find a hood with the adequate mount. The lenses tested were:

- ⌀72mm: different generations of the 17-70mm
- ⌀77mm: 10-20mm vs 120-400mm

Comment: The other aspect is related to the mount, which I'm not sure has the same bayonet

Comment: Will tell you later, I have two generations of the Sigma 17-70 (8 years apart) I'll see if their hoods are interchangeable and confirm. I also have  Sigma's 120-400mm and 10-20mm which I believe are both 77mm to check how far the lens hoods are compatible :)

Comment: Checked, and no hood fits any another lens.

Comment: Just one last question, since you have so many Sigma lenses (and hoods): I still have the original hood but it doesn't snap so firmly anymore. Also, it doesn't snap at all when reversed (i.e. for storage), is it normal? I can't recall if it ever did, as I bought it second hand

Comment: This is plastic, some part of the bayonet can be broken/worn out (mostly on the hood side).

Comment: That's why I was looking for a replacement (hoping it's the hood's fault)... so you conferm that they normally snap even when reversed?

Comment: Yes, they do, but I can't explain why they would snap only in one position. If the bayonet is damaged (hood or lens) this would apply to both storage and usage positions. Or it must be very marginal in the usage position.

Comment: Yes it is quite marginal, and I should look closer at what nudge allows that. Perhaps if I can thicken it with a drop of super glue (hood-side) I can make it firmer. Honestly, 40€ for a lens hood is way too much for me